# scipy pdist getting only two closest neighbors

Tags: python, scipy, pdist

I've been computing pairwise distances with scipy, and I am trying to get distances to two of the closest neighbors. My current working solution is:

```
dists = squareform(pdist(xs.todense()))
dists = np.sort(dists, axis=1)[:, 1:3]
```

However, the squareform method is spatially very expensive and somewhat redundant in my case. I only need the two closest distances, not all of them. Is there a simple workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using a KDTree? see [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy-spatial-kdtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between linear index and the (i, j) of the upper triangle distance matrix is not directly, or easily, invertible (see note 2 in [squareform doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform)).

However, by looping over all indices the inverse relation can be obtained:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def inverse_condensed_indices(idx, n):
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if k == idx:
                return (i, j)
            k +=1
    else:
        return None

# test
points = np.random.rand(8, 2)
distances = pdist(points)
sorted_idx = np.argsort(distances)
n = points.shape[0]
ij = [inverse_condensed_indices(idx, n)
      for idx in sorted_idx[:2]]

# graph
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
for i, j in ij:
    x = [points[i, 0], points[j, 0]]
    y = [points[i, 1], points[j, 1]]
    plt.plot(x, y, '-', color='red');

plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], '.', color='black');
plt.xlim(0, 1); plt.ylim(0, 1);
```

It seems to be a little faster than using `squareform`:

```
%timeit squareform(range(28))
# 9.23 µs ± 63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit inverse_condensed_indices(27, 8)
# 2.38 µs ± 25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was after!